# Is it possible to rewrite Volume Decals example from dx10 to OpenGL

Tags: opengl, directx

Is it possible to rewrite Volume Decals example from dx10 ([Humus - 3D](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=83)) to OpenGL?

Comment: Do you just want to know if it is *possible* (which it is), or do you want someone to do it for you?

Comment: No, I just want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to rewrite that demo using OpenGL. OpenGL and D3D expose more or less the same hardware functionality. OpenGL 3.3 is equivalent to D3D10.

Indeed, D3D10 isn't even required for the features of that demo. D3D9 could run it just fine.